# How to create pairs in sql query?

Tags: mysql

Could anyone tell me how to create pairs in MySQL. If you see the below query

```
select A.cakeid , A.ingredid from Contain as A inner join (select 
    cakeid, count(cakeid)
from
    Contain
group by cakeid
having count(cakeid) >= 3 ) as B on A.cakeid = B.cakeid 

OUTPUT:

Cakeid Ingredid
'1', '1'
'1', '3'
'1', '4'
'3', '1'
'3', '4'
'3', '5'
'5', '1'
'5', '2'
'5', '4'
'6', '1'
'6', '2'
'6', '3'
'6', '5'
'7', '1'
'7', '2'
'7', '3'
'7', '4'
'8', '1'
'8', '2'
'8', '3'
```

Could anyone tell me how can I create pairs of Cakeid which uses atleast three common ingredient ? For example, 6 and 7 are one pair which have three common ingredient.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Please choose one.

Comment: If MS SQL Server isn't involved, please remove that tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Self-join

```
select c1.cakeid cake1, c2.cakeid cake2, count(*) matching_Ingredid  
from Contain c1
join Contain c2 
    on c1.cakeid < c2.cakeid and c1.Ingredid = c2.Ingredid
group by c1.cakeid, c2.cakeid
having count(*) >= 3
```

Comment: Could you describe your query? I think it is giving me the right answer but need to understand how it is working

Comment: Why did you use this `c1.cakeid < c2.cakeid`

Comment: Okay I understood your approach. Thank you :)

Comment: Sorry, stepped away - glad it's clear.  You could do a <> as well, which would list each pair twice (which may or may not be what you want).

Answer (score 1):

The query below will give you the cakeids next to each other that contain more than 3 common ingredients.

```
select c1.cakeid as cakeid1, c2.cakeid as cakeid2 from
contain c1 inner join contain c2 on c1.ingredid=c2.ingredid and c1.cakeid<c2.cakeid
group by c1.cakeid, c2.cakeid
having count(*)>=3
```

To get the list you wanted from this, you need to join the above query once on the cakeid1, and once on the cakeid2 to the contain table again:

```
select c3.cakeid, c3.ingredid from content c3 inner join
(select c1.cakeid as cakeid1, c2.cakeid as cakeid2 from
contain c1 inner join contain c2 on c1.ingredid=c2.ingredid and c1.cakeid<c2.cakeid
group by c1.cakeid, c2.cakeid
having count(*)>=3) t1 on c3.cakeid=t1.cakeid1
union all
select c4.cakeid, c4.ingredid from content c4 inner join
(select c1.cakeid as cakeid1, c2.cakeid as cakeid2 from
contain c1 inner join contain c2 on c1.ingredid=c2.ingredid and c1.cakeid<c2.cakeid
group by c1.cakeid, c2.cakeid
having count(*)>=3) t2 on c4.cakeid=t2.cakeid2
```